# SQL Server Stored Procedure with UNC Path

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, unc

I have a Stored Procedure in which I'm mapping a Network Share Drive as a P:Drive and now I would like to remove the mapping and give the UNC path with both the username and password. Can someone please help me out in doing that?

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use P: "\\usanfsd01\Data" User1 /user:user /Persistent:Yes'  

DECLARE @cmd varchar(4000)
DECLARE @path varchar(2000)
SELECT @path='P:\*.csv'
SELECT @cmd = 'Dir "' + @path + '"'
```

Comment: you definitely DON'T want to do these types of tasks on SQL server, you are opening the door to get hacked, badly

Comment: The server is within the DMZ and there is no other way for me to achieve what I want to do other than this method, so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i really understand what you want to do, but to delete the mapping you would use

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use P: /delete'
```

Comment: In the above code instead of the mapping I would like to use the UNC path